# Reading/Writing several structs of unknown size to file C++

Tags: c++, database, file, file-io, fstream

I am wanting to make a book database to record what books I have read. So far, I have a structure for a book entry.

```
struct Entry
{
    string title;
    string author;
    int pages;
};
```

As you can see, the title and the author variables are of undetermined size. I would like to store several structures within one file, and then to read all those structures when I want to display the database.

How would I read/write several of these structures from a file? Would I have to have predetermined sizes? Please provide an example.

Comment: You would need to invent a file format that both describes and contains the data for example: <record-type><length-of-field><field-data><length-of-field><field-data> etc

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you add code, how you write to files?

Comment: XML or JSON could be a good format to save these info

Comment: The term to Google is *"serialisation of structs to a file"* or maybe *"serialization"*.

Comment: You could use `sqlite` which is an extremely simple database that doesn't require a server or any installation - that would also mean you could manage the database from the command-line very simply too... http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/tool/

Comment: @rak007 thanks, looking into XML

Comment: use JSON not XML. XML is sooo last century

Answer (score 1):

you could easily store it in a CSV-format the following way:

```
title_1,author_1,pages_1,title_2,author_2,pages_2,title_3,auth...
```

when reading back the file, then parse the file according to your separators and you have back your data.

*edit*:
as @Mark Setchell suggested you shouldn't use '`,`' as a separator, because a comma might also be part of the title itself. instead you should use a more rare character as separator, which isn't used very often in possible book titles. some examples are '`;`' '`|`' or '`#`' or even unprintable characters

Comment: As commas can appear in book titles, they are maybe not the best to use as separators for a CSV since a comma in the title is going to make your parser believe it has now moved on to the author... You may be happier with `|` as separators or even a NULL.